# AWS ALB: Path based routing not forwarding to target group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-alb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have created an ALB and a target group.

The ALB has a listener on `80`. This forwards it to my target group which in turn sends it to a registered instance on port `9000`.

I am trying to add a path based rule as follows:

[image]

However, when I am hitting `<alb-dns-name>`, I do get redirected to my registered instance.

When I try `<alb-dns-name>/portainer` I get `404`.

Am I missing sth?

Comment: Have you checked the app path? Most likely your path mapping is incorrect. If you are getting 404 that means your webapp is responding.

Comment: Where do I set the app path if I may ask?

Comment: The `/portainer` path btw does not exist in my application nowhere; I was just expecting that as soon as the ALB received the `/portainer` path, it would just simply redirected me to the tg; does the request convey the `/portainer` path to my target group instance?

Comment: It is a portainer (docker service)

Comment: Yes that I think is correct. Just try and add that to your app and test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path based routing also forwards the path to the respective request header;

So my app received `/portainer` in the request arriving to it and could not find/handle.

Switching to host based routing and the appropriate dns entries;